# How do I create this relational table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatable

Below is a portion of relational data base. I know how to create table Film and assign primary key to it.. but don't understate creating other tables and assigning primary key to it.
Any help?

[image]

table `Film`

```
CREATE TABLE Film (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  Year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (Year > 1900),
  Rating INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3 CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
);
```

how do I create table `FilmFormat` and `OrderItem` ?

Comment: Since your engine is MyISAM, CHECK constraints and FOREIGN KEY constraints will both be ignored by MySQL. No point defining them. The FK is created from FilmFormat to Film, so the Film table is complete as shown.

Comment: sorry I will remove engine then how it may work??

Comment: CHECK constraints will still get parsed and ignored.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `jy` (
  `PKfield` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field2` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PKfield`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK` FOREIGN KEY `FK` (`PKfield`)
    REFERENCES `Film` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: can you make it little bit clear?? can you make other table fields exactly in respective name??

Answer (score 0):

This is enough to show you how to create a foreign key constraint between the two tables.  As commented, the CHECK constraint will be parsed but ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE Film (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  Year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (Year > 1900),
  Rating INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3 CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
);

CREATE TABLE FilmFormat (
  FilmId INTEGER not null,
  FormatId INTEGER not null,
  Price decimal(16,4) null,
  Primary Key(FilmId, FormatId),
  Constraint FK_FilmFormat_FilmId FOREIGN KEY (FilmId) REFERENCES Film(Id)
);
```

Doing the last table will just be doing your work for you.